# Jest, Ошибка связанная со строками и toBe

Tags: javascript, jest

Можете подсказать, почему код jest крашится?

```
function reverseString(str){
    let str2 = str.split('')
                    .sort(() => -Infinity)
                        .join('');
    console.log(str2);
    return str;
}

module.exports = reverseString;
```

```
const reverseString = require('./task_01');

test(
    'Проверяем реверс строки', () => {
        expect(reverseString('hello www')).toBe('www olleh');
    });
```

Идентичный тест с сайта jest с суммой завершается успехом, но вот этот крашится, указывая на 5 строку и конкретно на toBe в ней.

```
Debugger attached.
 FAIL  task/task_01.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log
      www olleh

      at log (task/task_01.js:5:13)

  ● Проверяем реверс строки
                                                                                                                                     
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "www olleh"
    Received: "hello www"

      3 | test(
      4 |     "Проверяем реверс строки", () => {
    > 5 |         expect(reverseString("hello www")).toBe("www olleh");
        |                                            ^
      6 |     });

      at Object.toBe (task/task_01.test.js:5:44)
```

P.s. Оказалось, ошибка самого кода 1 части:

```
function reverseString(str){
    let reversedStr = str.split('').reverse().join('');
    console.log(reversedStr);
    return reversedStr;
}
```

Comment: "крашится" понятие растяжимое - приведите код ошибки.

Comment: @void добавил копию ошибки из терминала

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest говорит что он ожидал строку 'www olleh', а пришло 'hello www'. Проблема в том, что функция возвращает str вместо str2

Comment: Если точнее, то ожидалось str,а пришло rts. Но не str2 вместо str

Comment: @SwaD Я имел ввиду, что функция возвращает переменную str, а должна str2.  return str; - Вот тут